# Importing 'recaptcha' in Python server on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, recaptcha

I'm having a problem importing `recaptcha` in my Python server on GAE.

At present, I solve it by adding the `recaptcha` source code (`class RecaptchaClient`) manually.

How can I "make" GAE import it in the same way it imports other "standard" packages?

If this is not feasible, then is there any alternative package provided by GAE?

Comment: I don't think it's "standard" packages and not listed in supported 3rd party library (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27), hence the only way to import it is adding the source code manually

Comment: I suggest you read the Python Runtime Docs, especially the section on pure python which covers use of 3rd party libs not included in the runtime https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_Pure_Python

Comment: Thank you @Tim Hoffman. I was aware of unsupported operations like writing to the filesystem, but I was not aware of the restriction on including any C extensions or other code that must be compiled. How can I tell whether or not a Python module contains such code then?

Comment: About the only way is read the docs.  See what dependancies it has and look at the code.  If its a python wrapper around some popular library it may will not work.  For example lxml was explicitly added to the python appengine supported 3rd party libraries some time back, as was PIL as both had 'c' dependencies.